# VBA: Delete target row if cell contains text?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet like so:

Column Y
Remove
Remove
Remove
Remove

I want the user to be able to delete each row by clicking each of the remove texts. This should delete only the row which the user has clicked remove for, aka the target row.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 25 And Target.Value = "Remove" Then
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
End Sub
```

for some reason this does nothing.

I also want to add a condition which only deletes those rows from row 17 onwards.

Please can someone show me how to get this working correctly? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 25 And .Row > 16 And .value = "Remove" Then .EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. This does seem to work 50/50. If i close my workbook and open it again, and click to delete the rows then the rows delete. However, if i repopulate the cells again, then it doesnt work and i have to close the workbook and reopen it each time for this to work :(

Comment: It works for me. Please elaborate on what's happening to you.

Comment: did you get through it?

Comment: yes thank you i managed to resolve it since i had not enabled events. appreciate your help.

Comment: you are welcome. so my answer _was_ the solution, wasn't it? it also handles the "from row 17 onward" _added_ condition, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with the Workbook_SheetSelectionChange event.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 25 And Target.Value = "Remove" Then
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
End Sub
```

Also you can verify that events are enabled by running:

```
Sub EnableEvents()
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```